# Compare two array backwards without knowing the position of the last element

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have two arrays, such as

```
int a[10];
int b[5]={1,3,5,7,9};
```

However, I don't how many elements are in array `a`. I mean the size of array `a` is 10, but `a` could contain any number of elements between 1 to 10. I want to compare these two arrays backward. Thus how can I check at which position does array `a` start to have a valid number?

Another question is can I declare an array without initializing it? If I can, then when I call the element in the array does it return some random garbage or just null?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` ? So you know the size.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your array (all elements of array) with some known integer (say -1 ) then iterate through it (the modified indexes will have value other than -1) until -1 is encountered. This is only temporary solution.Because -1 is also valid integer and it may not be the exact solution to the problem.
I would really like to get better solution from experts of SO.
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find first the first valid position for a first. This is c++14:

```
auto valid_pos = std::find_if(std::crbegin(a), std::crend(a), [](int val) { /*your predicate*/ });

bool are_equal = std::equal(std::crbegin(b), std::crend(b), valid_pos, std::crend(a));
```

This is making use of c++14 free functions for iterators and improvement in `std::equal` that checks size and does not cause undefined behaviour, unlike the old 3-legged `std::equal` algorithm.

About returning from an unitialized array: it will return random data, but not a null value in the sense of `NULL` or `nullptr` in C++. Because the element type is an int, not a pointer. Only pointers can hold values `NULL` or `nullptr` when we talk about basic types. User defined types is another story because they can be customized.

P.S.: When using C++, do not use `NULL`, use `nullptr` always. `NULL` can lead to subtle bugs in the presence of overloading, among other problems.

Comment: **−1**  “Only pointers can be null” is silly disinformation. Also the presented code hides the not necessarily correct assumption of initialization behind otherwise needless complexity.

Comment: Re "in which way using the standard library is worse than writing raw loops", this indicates that I've said something like that. I have not. You could post this as an SO question, but it would probably be closed fast as too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: Re "About the null thing". This is about the statement that "Only pointers can be null". I think you have in mind a special nullvalue distinct from ordinary valid values. But (1) that's not clear at all to a reader who doesn't know about such values, because the term *null* just means *zero*, (2) that's not how it works with pointers in C++ (the C++ pointer nullvalue is not distinct, e.g. it can be reached via pointer arithmetic), and (3) integers can be null, in the ordinary sense of zero, and with some implementations floating point types can have special "invalid" values in addition to zero

Comment: SO comments are really too short for a good discussion. But summing up, in C++ floating point types are the only kind of built-in type that can have really special "invalid" values, nullvalues in the special sense, e.g. the one commonly called NaN for Not a Number. Pointers have a nullvalue that's not so special, that can be reached via ordinary expressions. Integers can be null in the ordinary sense of zero.

Comment: Regarding my assertion about terminology, "null" meaning "zero", some references with the common usage. C++14 §2.2/5 " it is converted to an implementation-defined member other than the null (wide) character. ", referring to the integer value 0. C++14 §2.3/3 " plus a null character (respectively, null wide character), whose representation has all zero bits.".

Comment: Well, I see your point. Will correct that. As a side note, when I was explained about null in a first year degree, they did not go with the gory details so far, even if this is not completely accurate :) By null I mean NULL and nullptr. Now you will tell me you can create a user-defined type and assign NULL or nullptr also, but I was talking in the context of basic value types vs pointers, which, in the context of the question, I think, is understandable.

Comment: This is language-lawyer level. I think that was out of scope for the question. Maybe I can refine it a bit more, but... I think it is better at least. I will put a warning.

Answer (score 0):

With the declaration

```
int a[10];
```

and valid items set to 1 through 10, consecutively from the start, you ask:

> **”** how can I check at which position does array `a` start to have a valid number?

- If `a` is at namespace scope, then `a` is guaranteed zero-initialized, and you can search for the first zero. Be careful about not indexing beyond the end of the array. `std::find` does this correctly for you.
- Otherwise the standard provides no guarantee about initialization (since the type `int` does not provide such a guarantee), and the end of valid data can't be found in a portable context-independent way. You can still, however, rely on contextual guarantees, including compiler-specific guarantees. For example, when you know that the `a` object has been zeroed by your code, you have a contextual guarantee.

**Edit**: *At least two persons find the above so misleading that they have downvoted, because allegedly someone might think that observed behavior with one given system and compiler, is a guarantee. I.e., it's allegedly possible to read “guarantee” as just “belief”, and then think that this answer states that one can rely on beliefs. The above should not be read with such reinterpretation.*

Regarding

> **”** can I declare an array without initializing it?

Yes.

> **”** If I can, then when I call the element in the array does it return some random garbage or just null?

See above.

---

All this said, do consider using **`std::vector`** instead of raw arrays.

It maintains a dynamic length for you.

Comment: -1 because there's no such thing as a "contextual guarantee". The standard is pretty clear: it's undefined behaviour (and not implementation defined). Moreover it's not just the compiler that's involved here: BSD systems zero memory on allocation, so code that runs fine there won't anywhere else.

Comment: "For example, when you know that the a object has been zeroed by your code, [...]" You can't know that (verifiably), which is why suggesting it - alongside the strong word "guarantee" - is IMHO extremely misleading.

Comment: The idea that one can't know that one has provided a guarantee, is incorrect.

Comment: The BSD note is only a simple example of what might be the consequence of such a misunderstanding of that part of your answer: If one develops on a BSD system, and sees in every check they run that their variables are zeroed, then this could be mistaken for some kind of guarantee. Shipping that code to some non BSD system will then only reveal the bugs. Code with UB in it is just wrong code, so it shouldn't be suggested as solution.

Comment: So you mean... that if somebody relies on a mistaken belief, somehow inspired by this answer, it could be Bad. Well. I surely didn't aim to inspire in such way, and don't know how to un-inspire.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is misleading. If you can rely on your code or compiler zeroing out the array, I find the phrase "contextual guarantee" to be quite fitting.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that your answer couldn't lead to someone belief that using undefined behaviour would be appropriate. I think your note makes this clear enough, so I'm taking back my down vote. (Sorry that I'm a bit pedantic about that, but about seemingly half of the questions here are related to UB, so I think one needs to be clear with that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) since it is flexible enough and it has access to the size and even an iterator to the last element

OR if you don't need to access all the elements but the last element in the array, you may want to use [Stacks](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) since it is easier to get the element at the back of the stack

Remember to try looking for other libraries and not sticking to only using arrays, it will most of the time make things easier for you